# check for appearance of multiple strings in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I got a database with multiple fields and about 10000 entries. I only need to check for the appearance of 4 different strings in one field.

Example:

```
id--name--sex--color--size--weight--price--points--class--
1   pet   m    white  180   90      120    1000    low
2   bob   m    white  180   90      110    2000    high
3   foo   m    white  180   90      120    3000    low
4   boo   m    white  180   90      140    1000    low
5   bla   m    white  180   90      100    2000    medium
6   blu   m    white  180   90      120    5000    lala
```

Basically there are 3 classes, but sometimes I have a custom class. Now I want to search my whole DB for the appearance of low, high and medium. It might be that there is no entry for one or more of them. Also I need to check whether there is a custom (unknown) class. 
It's enough to know whether they appear, I don't need any more data.

All I came up with is just querying the field `class` and then searching with phps `in_array()`, but I guess that's just a waste of resources.

Can someone help me here please ? How do I query this clever without querying all the results?

Comment: SQL has a [WHERE clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html). That should do it for you with the SQL query already.

Comment: Yeah but then I'd have to do 4 queries to keep each keyword covered - seems overloaded. Is that the only way ?

Comment: No you can use logical operators or the IN function to do that with one query. Additionally there are aggregate functions (GROUP BY).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let database find only distinct values from class column. Your keyword is 'distinct'.

```
select DISTINCT class from table;
```

Anyway if you care I would recommend reading something about database table normalization and improving the table design.

Comment: Yes, welcome! Have a +1 worth 10 rep to keep you coming back for more.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not simply query for counts, `GROUP BY class`?  This will return all classes, including your custom ones.

```
SELECT class, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY class;
```

Or simply `DISTINCT class`

```
SELECT DISTINCT class FROM table
```